# SQL Server Reporting Services date Format

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have date format like 01 Jan 0001 in SSRS ,how can i check and assign empty value to this type of date?

Comment: Could you be a tad more talkative and explain what excactly is your problem?

Comment: An answer as concise as your question: with `IIF`

Comment: can you give me hint of code?

Comment: =IIF(Fields!IssueDate.Value="01 Jan 0001","","") I have add like this in Expression property and my code works. Thanx

Comment: =IIF(Fields!IssueDate.Value="01 Jan 0001","",Fields!IssueDate.Value)